# Better understanding the life cycle of lasioderma serricorne (cigarette beetle, cigar beetle, tobacco beetle, drugstore beetle)

Tags: zoology, entomology, life-history, lifespan, cycle

Lasioderma serricorne, commonly known as the cigarette beetle, cigar beetle, tobacco beetle, or drugstore beetle:

- Live 2–4 weeks.
- The female beetle lays as many as 100 eggs loosely on the substrate to be fed upon.
- The larval period usually ranges from four to five months, but under very favorable conditions the development from egg to adult may occur in 6 to 8 weeks.
- When the larvae are fully-grown, pupation occurs and they remain in this resting stage for 12 to 18 days.
- The complete life cycle takes 26 days at 37 °C and 120 days at 20 °C.
- In the Northeast (presumably USA, as the primary source is a USA university), there is usually only one generation per year.

*Sources:

http://idl.entomology.cornell.edu/wp-content/uploads/Cigarette-and-Drugstore-Beetles.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasioderma_serricorne*

So it appears their life history cycle is:

```
EGG -> LARVA -> PUPATING -> ADULT
       2-5MO    12-18DAY    2-4WK
```

Given that the total cycle duration is much less a year, why do some regions only experience one generation per year?

Are the eggs just sitting for months on the substrate without hatching into larvae?

Comment: What happens when cold? Often eggs or pupae wait until warmer.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler Thanks for your comment.  Would that mean in a climate-controlled environment they will prosper year-round?

Comment: With other indoor pests in climate controlled house; they do live and breed constantly year round.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler Thank you for the update.